# DOCKER_BUILDKIT environment variable expects boolean value

Tags: python, docker-compose, pycharm, docker-buildkit

[The result of the make build command in shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAduJ.png)
I try to build the docker images on PyCharm Windows, running the make command in powershell and trying to execute DOCKER_BUILDKIT i got results:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT environment variable expects boolean value: strconv.ParseBool: parsing "1 ": invalid syntax
```

In the Docker Daemon I got this configuration:[Docker daemon configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaMKc.png)

What can be done to make it recieve the boolean value?
When i write to the command line command like this:

```
set DOCKER_BUILDKIT=True && docker build --ssh default -f docker/Dockerfile -t basketball_backend_api_core .
```

I still got the same mistake.

Comment: `set "DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1" && docker ...` - otherwise cmd/PowerShell interprets the space right after `1` or `True` as part of the env var value

Comment: Makes sense. Was not entirely sure, why would cmd/PS reinterpret explicit True value as 1, or even "True " as "1 ".

Comment: @Zecharian Lvov also, could You please ditch the images with input/output and provide it in propert text form (copy/paste)? To make it more usable for any future cases.

Comment: The error seems to be that you have a space after `1` and so it rejects it because of that. If you trim off the space I believe it should work again.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, thank you! set "DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1" && docker ... resulted in another problem, but worked, thank you!

Comment: @Kamiccolo unfortunately I still do not have an option to paste pictures normally

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Another possible way was set %DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1% && docker ...